# ktdatatable load by ajax as append row but cloumn header width not same data column width

Tags: ajax, pagination

ktdatatable load by ajax as append row but cloumn header width not same data column width
but after inspector my page it's show normal
i am using Metronic 5 and codeigniter 3

[exp.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYlh1.png)

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner">




                  <table class="table-separate table-striped table-head-custom table-hover table-bordered proj_table" id="kt_datatable2_wrapper">
                   <thead>
                      <tr>
                        
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Project Code</th>
                       .
                       .

                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                  </table>
                  <div id='pagination'></div>
                </div>
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
      url: '<?= base_url() ?>projectManagment/loadData/' + pageNum,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(responseData) {
        $('#pagination').html(responseData.pagination);
        paginationData(responseData.progData, responseData.permission);
         $('#loading').hide();
      }
    });

 function paginationData(data, permission) {
    $('.proj_table tbody').empty();
    for (projs in data) {
        .....

  $('.proj_table tbody').append(progRow);

    }
```

it's some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear what your question is. Are you asking why the cells in the table body aren't aligned with the corresponding column headings? Also, please show how the value of `progRow` is set.